# mAh and Wh ratings not matching with voltage of device

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, amperage, energy, watts

I was under the impression that
Wh = Ah * V

I have a [20000mAh battery charging device for my phone](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B00R97DNHE/ref=od_aui_detailpages00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) but am confused about the information provided by it on the side.

It claims to have a 5V output (3.1A max), and a capacity of "20000mAh/74Wh". But following the above equation, 100Wh = 20Ah * 5V. Where does this discrepancy come from?

Comment: The battery voltage is 3.7 V. It has a step up converter to 5 V after it. You are trading current for voltage. Recalculate for 3.7 V instead. On the outside you will see (3.7/5) times less Ah, minus efficiency losses.

Comment: this discrepancy is still probably smaller than the "advertised power vs real power" discrepancy

Comment: As @winny says, it's the 3.7 V Ah capacity and not the 5 V. This is one good reason to use Wh. It's a measure of the energy available.

Comment: @winny You should make this an answer.

Comment: @DoxyLover It will just be downvoted and/or removed.

Comment: @winny 3.7/5 seems to be exactly .74, so that would definitely be a good explanation. To me it really feels like false advertising though. If I have a 5V, 1A device, I would expect it to run for 20 hours on a full charge of this. But it will actually be 74% of that by this equation. Am I the only one that sees this as a snaky?

Comment: I never understood Ah to begin with. It just seems like it's there to intentionally confuse and mislead people

Comment: @Cruncher Yes, anything to sell. The Wh rating is what you should be concered about.

Answer (score 2):

This answer was originally by @winny in comments. He isn't interested in making it an answer so I'm doing so as I feel it is a valid answer and should be posted as such.

The internal battery is most likely Lithium-Ion, producing 3.7 volts (nominal), which is fed into a boost-regulator to produce 5 volts. The 20 Ah rating is on the battery, not the 5 volt output. Thus, 20Ah * 3.7V = 74Wh.