# (External Battery) If i have Portable Charger that has a capacity of 50,000 mAh and

Tags: batteries, amperage

4 ports with 2 amps, 2 amps, 1 amp, and 1 amp that can charge 4 phones respectively. How long will the battery continue to charge these phones, assuming they are pulling the largest load possible?

Based on my calculations

[image]

the battery will last for as long as: 5.619 hours. However, this number feels funny to me. I've simply added all the loads together and then divided it from 33,716 mAh (this [number](https://www.amazon.com/review/RGN53V0717A7M/ref=cm_cr_rdp_perm?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B00YP823NA) was gained by accounting for inefficiency in the output).

Comment: The Ah rating is probably for the internal 3.7 volt battery, not for the 5 volt output, so you need to divide by (5/3.7). Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/245861/mah-and-wh-ratings-not-matching-with-voltage-of-device/246117#246117

Comment: The rating is correct I assure you. Click on the word "number"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Battery is 185 Wh rated, which translates to 37 Ah (185 Watts x Hours = 185 Volts x Amps x Hours, 185 Volts x Amps x Hours/5 Volts = 37 Ah). Assuming the review is correct and the battery is 91% of rated capacity, that translates to 34 usable Ah. 34 Amps x Hours/6 Amps = 5.6 Hours.

So yes, you are correct.

NOTE: If it seems like the numbers are off (ex. 34/6 rounds to 5.7), that's because I rounded to 2 significant figures for the numbers I gave but kept all digits for the next steps of the calculations.